# Oracle Comparing varchar2 field with number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query in which I have following sub-query

`(select account from asl_data where alias_accunt = trim(field) )`

where alias_account is varchar2(20), while the field value comes from substr from another sub-query. However the value of comes as 00123456789

For this I am getting error as invalid number. I tried to_char, cast functions on both fields. But nothing seem to work.

I am missing something? Any suggestion on this?

Thank you!!

Comment: No, `trim(number)` should result in an implicit conversion to a character... so, there's probably something you're not telling us. Have you run this sub-query on its own? Was there an error? Are there any functions? Can you provide the query and table structures?

Comment: Your comparison is between two character fields, if your explanation is correct.  This should not generate an "invalid number" error, since no numbers are involved.

Comment: This query is part of a generic proc where the subquery for field is genereated at runtime. I have run the field subquery that is generated independently and it works.

Comment: @VarunNaik . . . Check if the account is being used as a number outside this subquery.  Perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: The account field was used else where and that is where I was getting the error. My bad, I was looking at wrong place

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in this query/procedure, there is an attempt to implicitly convert a string to a number. Probably in your subquery, or probably because the variable declaration is a number for one of your variables. Nothing seems to be wrong with the example you posted though.

Once you identify the field, you can see the rows that are causing this problem using a query like this.

```
with t1 as 
(
    select '100' id1, 'first' name1 from dual
    union all
    select '100A' id1, 'second' name1 from dual
    union all
    select '$$1' id1, 'third' name1 from dual
)
select * from t1

100    first
100A   second
$$1    third
```

If you try to convert id to a number, the first one will work (may be your example is such a case), but the others would raise error.

```
with t1 as
(
    select '100' id1, 'first' name1 from dual
    union all
    select '100A' id1, 'second' name1 from dual
    union all
    select '$$1' id1, 'third' name1 from dual
)
select id1,
       name1,
       to_number(id1)
   from t1

/

ERROR:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

To identify the rows that have this problem, use...

```
with t1 as 
(
    select '100' id1, 'first' name1 from dual
    union all
    select '100A' id1, 'second' name1 from dual
    union all
    select '$$1' id1, 'third' name1 from dual
)
select id1, 
       name1
       --,replace( translate( id1, '0123456789', '0000000000' ), '0', '' ),
       --length(replace( translate( id1, '0123456789', '0000000000' ), '0', '' ))
   from t1
   where length(replace( translate( id1, '0123456789', '0000000000' ), '0', '' )
               ) <> 0

id1     name1
---------------
100A    second
$$1     second
```